# Why compiler does not saw breakpoints inside the decorated with macro function parameters parameter list (lambdas)

Tags: c++, lambda, macros, runtime, breakpoints

There code

**definition**:

```
template <typename T>
void callback(T&& lambda);

#define CALLBACK(lambda) callback(lambda)
```

**runtime**:

```
callback([=]{
   printf("Hi man!");   // first case: here can be placed breakpoint
});

CALLBACK([=]{
   printf("Hi again!");  // second case: breakpoint can't be placed here
});
```

in the first case, the breakpoint can be placed inside the lambda. But in second case (with decorated with macro) can't be. Why? Are there ways to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver, VS2015

Comment: nvm.  can confirm.